# Trailing stop, Unable to Use While loop

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

```
`// Enter short position
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, stop=short_stop_loss)    

 while strategy.position_size > 0
   if close < entryprice + .03
       // Exit trade with .03% loss
      strategy.close("Exit on .03% loss", "Short", loss=profit_target + .03)
   else if close >= entryprice * 2
      // Exit trade with the take profit level
      strategy.close("Short TP", "Short", profit=short_take_profit)`
```

Currently Im trying to write code for a loop to where it closes the entry position, I do have the other inputs defined so that is not a problem,but I get a error stating

Compilation error. Line 128: Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

I''ve attempted to look this up and try different ways to write this, but at last I need a loop that checks the conditions. I wont be able to just do a if else statement.I dont understand what error this is giving me. Please help

I attempted to look up while loops and I was thinking strategy.close as a possibly to help. But I am unsure.

Comment: did you still have your compilation error ?

Answer (score 0):

your error 'Compilation error. Line 128: Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'' comes from the first block of 'if' : the two lines after your 'if' statement should respect the same indentation (as your 'else if'  statement).
The corrected version is :

```
if close < entryprice + .03
    // Exit trade with .03% loss
    strategy.close("Exit on .03% loss", "Short", loss=profit_target + .03)
```

Look closely : the two line have now the same indentation

Comment: ive done just a if statement and a loop and a if statement inside, but what I am wanting is when strategy.entry enters the position, it will then check the conditions to exit, I cant make a indent on the comment section and says to many characters so I tried doing // as a indent type of deal, hope its not to confusing. My code does state that its running too long, sometimes, and sometimes when i change it, it only does 1 output.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it solve your compilation error and open a new question with your other problem, you will get help. For information 'code' and questions are forbidden in comments